# How to "post" image URL instead of Image to Vision Cognitive API?

Tags: python-2.7, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

Here is the code i used:

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.projectoxford.ai')
conn.request("POST", "/vision/v1.0/ocr?%s" % params,"{'Url':'my_url_xxxxxxxxxx'}", headers_1)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)
```

This is the error I got:

```
{
    "code":"InvalidImageUrl",
    "requestId":"3e074556-dd52-4965-b250-e821b7fb6c27",
    "message":"Image URL is not accessible."
}
```

Comment: Is the URL publicly reachable?

Comment: yes it is reachable . I have put many other Urls in the above format but none is working. This above code is working perfectly fine if I input a local image.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Image Url : https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8c/1b/82/8c1b825d2d0750957098c8a4a879d53f.jpg

Comment: Error : {"code":"InvalidImageFormat","requestId":"987d9af6-717d-4fe8-af26-9f3135c41155","message":"Input data is not a valid image."}

Comment: yes its accessible.

Answer (score 1):

Your payload needs to be properly cased: `"{'url':'https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8c/1b/82/8c1b825d2d0750957098c8a4a879d53f.jpg'}"`, note lower-case `url`, not `Url`.

Comment: still not working. the same error "Invalid image Format"

Comment: Well, it's not the image, since it "works" both on the [demo page](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api) as well as the [API console](https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc/console)

Comment: You also need to specify the content type to application/json. That's what was missing.

Answer (score 0):

The error got corrected.
I used small cps 'url' instead of "Url" and also changed type to json

## api details

headers_1 = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '*************************' #My valid Key
}

---

conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.projectoxford.ai')
conn.request("POST", "/vision/v1.0/ocr?%s" % params,"{'url':'my_url_xxxxxxxxxx'}", headers_1)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)